# Add condition in SQL query based on table value

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am using oracle as my database. I want to add condition in sql query based on table data. In the table if CT_GENERAL is 1 then i want to add another condition in my sql query.( CST_GENERAL = USER ARGUMENT ).

select * from ch_caseinfo  where
    case when ct_general = 1
            then cst_general = %3
    end

%3 = Funding

//TABLE STRUCTURE
//CH_CASEINFO

VOLUMEID | CT_ADVERSE | CT_GENERAL | CT_HA | CT_MI | CST_GENERAL | CST_MI

```
149634          0          0          0          0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
161077          0          0          0          0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
161147          0          1          0          1 Funding          Composition/ingredients                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
161268          0          1          0          0 Funding                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
161306          0          1          0          0 Manufacturing                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
240131          0          1          1          0 Funding                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
239364          0          0          0          0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
239364          0          0          0          0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
147434          0          0          0          0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
147466          0          0          0          0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
158990          0          1          0          1 Funding          Administration                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

 98863          1          1          1          1 Funding          Disposal                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
159757          1          1          1          1 Funding          Disposal                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 98863                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
191039          1          1          0          0 Other                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 97007          0          0          0          0
```

ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"

Answer (score 0):

You need to form your where clause to evaluate an expression that is true when you don't want to include the filter (CT_GENERAL is 0).  Considering the example below, if ct_general = 0 then cst_general will always equal cst_general (unless null -- if that is a possibility, you need to accommodate nulls).

```
SELECT *
FROM ch_caseinfo
WHERE CASE WHEN ct_general = 0 THEN cst_general ELSE USERARGUMENT END = cst_general
    AND OTHERCRITERIA = CRITERIA
```